# Javascript Revealing Module Pattern - this and internal function calls

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

I've been using the [Revealing Module pattern](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/08/02/techniques-strategies-and-patterns-for-structuring-javascript-code-revealing-module-pattern.aspx) in my Javascript lately to help structure my code and everything has gone well.  However, I'm a bit confused by this code snippet:

```
function vm() {
    var pub = function () {
        alert("from pub: " + this);
        pri();
    },
    pri = function () {
        alert("from pri: " + this);
    };

    return {
        pub: pub,
        pri: pri
    };
}
var it = new vm();
it.pub();
it.pri();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zreFY/)

When I call `pub()` and `pri()` directly, `this` refers to the current instance of `vm`.  However, when I call `pri()` from within `pub()` suddenly `this` has reverted to referring to the global window object.  I thought one of the objectives of the revealing module pattern was to remove the issues with `this` but it appears that when calling a function from within another function I'm losing the value of `this`.

Does anyone know why this if and if there's a way to get this to work without having to pass references to the current object around?

Comment: No. The objective of the revealing module pattern was always and only to provide a private scope. Btw, you don't even use the RMP, but a constructor approach (though `new` is not helpful when you're explicitly `return`ing an object).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example combines three of the four ways in which to invoke a function.

#### Constructor Invocation

```
var it = new vm();
```

Inside of `function` `vm`, `this` refers to the *object instance you are returning*.  This is expected.

#### Method Invocation

```
it.pub();
```

Inside of `function` `pub`, this refers to *the same object instance as is referenced by `it`*. Again, this is expected.

#### Function Invocation

```
pri();
```

Inside of `function` `pri`, `this` refers to the **global object**. This is not expected, and is considered to be a mistake in the JavaScript language. The 'pub' function was invoked with the method invocation pattern, and so it is natural to assume the `this` should always point to the current function/object when used inside it.

One remedy is to store your returned object in a local variable inside the vm method, and then due to scoping, `pub` and `pri` methods will be able to reference the object instance safely.

```
function vm() {
    var pub = function () {
        alert("from pub: " + that);
        pri();
    },
    pri = function () {
        alert("from pri: " + that);
    };

    var that = {
        pub: pub,
        pri: pri
    };

    return that;
}
```

Comment: more on this: http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/javascript/9780596517748/functions/invocation

Comment: Thanks for this - I'd already figured out ways to deal with the issue I was seeing in my real code although I do like the way you are dealing with it.  I guess the information I was reading about the revealing module pattern slightly exaggerated it's effectiveness in clearing up issues with "this" unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `pri()` Inside `pub` actually calls the captured `pri` variable which is in scope. Calling it like this without a target object will set `this` to the global (window) object.

You may want to read about how `this` works in Javascript, because it is very much unlike other object-oriented languages you may know. `this` is dynamic and changes depending on how you invoke the method.

In your case the fix is easy enough: call the function like that: `this.pri()`. This will properly call the `pri` member of the current `this` object (i.e. `var it`), with `this` set to `this`... if this sentence makes any sense!

Never think you can omit `this.` in javascript code, like you could in C# or Java.

Answer (score 0):

As others have it well-explained, I just provide you with a technic to keep your context tight on your object. You could use `bind` to tight your object with the current context. Caution, not all browsers supports it (old versions of IE fail). Besides the technic has enthusiasts and opponents.

```
return {
  pub: pub.bind(this),
  pri: pri.bind(this)
};
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/zreFY/1/**